# org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper - InetAddress is now DOWN

Tags: cassandra

I have one, three node Cassandra Cluster Community Edition V4.1.2 with (4) Cores on each node, and 32GB of memory on each node and 28TB of disk space on each node.

In my cassandra logs (/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log) I get a lot of these INFO messages:
"INFO org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper - InetAddress /192.xxx.xx.xx is now DOWN"
"INFO org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper - InetAddress /192.xxx.xx.xx is now UP"

We use DataStax OpsCentre as our frontend, and also see it in those eventlogs for the same times as INFO and WARNINGS:
"Node reported as being down:192.xxx.xx.xx"
"Node reported as being up:192.xxx.xx.xx"

Is this something that should be happening, if not, where can I go investigate as to why this is happening?

Regards

Comment: Is it happening frequently?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sign that something is unhealthy in your cluster. The most common cause is that one or more of your nodes is overloaded and probably overwhelmed with garbage collection. Cassandra logs anytime GC takes longer than 200ms so if this is your problem you should see messages about GC in the remote node's logs.

If nodes are not overloaded then you might have network issues.

Comment: We experience these issues with very little load, we do 37writes per second and 0.3ms write request latency per operation.
Disk utilization is at 8%.

I will sit with our network engineers to see if we can identify any network issues.

Comment: No GC messages as such, the only thing I can see in the logs regarding GC is that we have huge amounts of tombstone data, so much so that our applications select queries hit the tombstone threshold and drops the query:

Comment: WARN org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter - Read 266931 live and 42236 tombstoned cells in #######.edgestore (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 2147483647 columns was requested, slices=[40-80], delInfo={deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=2147483647}
13/06/2014 08:20:10,636 TRACE org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper - Gossip Digests are : /###.###.##.##:1401402289:3744232 /###.###.##.##:1401402174:3743335 /XXX.XXX.XX.XX:1401971120:2026444

Comment: we are getting the same issue very frequently.Please suggest how you solve it.We do not have tombstone .No clue why this is happening.. 34 Gossiper.java:1034 - InetAddress /10.XXX.YYY.ZZZ is now DOWN